# Preventing user manipulation exploit of REST URLs

Tags: javascript, rest, express, routes, javascript-injection

I'm trying to figure out how I should prevent an exploit where the user modifies the URL of -for example- a GET request. The code below is a route on my Express router that handles the incoming request to go into a collection, let's say for the sake of argument it's collection "A", and returns the a few things from that collection.

```
   router.get("/word/:collection/:language/:amount", function(req, res) {
       getItems(req, res);
   }
```

Now, if the user changes the `:collection` section in the URL in the front-end Javascript code to "B", he will get collection "B". How do I prevent this? In the case of things like collections that hold the userIDs I can just bar them from accessing these based on `req.user` (I think?) but in this case I can't do that because the user does need to have access to both collection A and B, I just want to restrict them from going in there at the wrong time (both are needed on different pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest endpoints that contain information only certain users should have access to need be secured. (The most common method being an API token being passed to the API, oAuth tokens, or a login cookie). If userA should not be accessing collectionB, you need to do a check within that resource, and return some type of error code to the browser.

The standard error most website's implement is [`401: Unauthorized`](https://httpstatuses.com/401). Here's a simple example:

```
router.get("/word/:collection/:language/:amount", function(req, res) {
    if ( !hasAccess(req.params.userToken) )
    {
        return res.send(401, {success: false, message: 'no permission'});
    }
    var collection = req.params.collection,
    var language = req.params.language,
    var amount = req.params.amount;
    return getItems(req, res, collection, language, amount);
}
```

Edit: After rereading your question, I now realize that the user will need to have access to both collections at one point or another. In this case, you'll still need to implement some server side validation. Here's another example (With quizzes/answers):

```
router.get("/quiz/finish/:id", function(req, res) {
    //Store that this user has taken this quiz
    return recordQuizAnswers(req.params.userToken, req.params.quizAnswers);
}

router.get("/quiz/answers/:id", function(req, res) {
    //Has this user taken this quiz?
    if ( !hasUserTakenQuiz(req.params.userToken) )
    {
        return res.send(401, {success: false, message: 'Trying to get the answers before taking the quiz? Cheater...'});
    }
    return getQuizAnswers(req.params.id);
}
```

Edit 2: After seeing your comment, I've thought of another solution that you can use. Use [UUID](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid#uuidv4options--buffer--offset)'s for id's instead of auto-incrementing numbers. This will prevent the user from simply adding/subtracting to get different quizzes.

Comment: Thank you. Though that's not quite what I mean, I think. It's more a case of "what if I have to get the data for a specific quiz while having multiple quizzes available to the user in general" and have a .get that looks like this:"router.get("/quiz/:quizID/answers/", function(req, res)...." If I manipulate the "quizID" I will get the answers for the wrong quiz. User has access to both these quizzes, I just don't want him to screw with the URL and get the wrong one at the wrong time.

Comment: Hmmm, but if I understand this correctly I could still exploit it if I go to Page A, note down the UUID that I use for that collection, go to page B, change the UUID in the Javascript and get the collection for Page A.

Comment: But what do you want from me? They have access to both resources...if they go to one page, they can simply download everything on that page, and go back to the other page. They wouldn't even need to make another request on that other page.

Comment: In that case maybe I want something that's not possible. I wanted to "lock someone in" to a certain page I suppose. Prevent them from querying collections at moments when they are not relevant to the user and only a collection when it's needed.

Comment: "Locking them in" wouldn't work for the reason in my previous comment. They could simply download the results, go to the other page, and just access their local saved data. That being said: You could generate one time use tokens that you'd have to pass back to your callback on your page. Once the data is fetched, clear the token.